# a confusing way to define C structure

Tags: c

I am a newbie in C and I stumbled on this c-structure:

```
typedef struct
{
   int dog;
   int cat;
} FOO;

typedef struct
{
   int  id;
   FOO* pRow[0]
} BAR;
```

I know basic c and c++ but I have no idea the motivation of the following line: "FOO* pRow[0]".

If the author wants to define a pointer to an array of FOO, then he/she should just define it as "FOO* pROW", right? Why does pROW[0] stands for in this case then?

Please enlighten me.
Thanks!

Comment: It's called a "flexible array member": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member

Comment: @AndrewMedico: It isn't. It's a [zero-length array](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html).

Comment: @AndrewMedico a flex array is an actual language feature in C99, this is a hack.

Answer (score -2):

the `pRow`  is an **array of pointers**. the first element ,`pRow[0]` is pointing to a FOO struct.

if you write `FOO* pRow`,  then the pRow is simply one pointer

Comment: Not really, because you can allocate it to N sizeof(FOO), and then it would't be one pointer.